Is an email legally binding for a governmental job confirmation in Germany?
Here is an excerpt from the email:

es ist mir eine große Freude, Ihnen heute mitzuteilen, dass Ihre Bewerbung XXX erfolgreich war. Wir möchten Sie gerne zum nächstmöglichen Datum einstellen. Der Personalrat hat bereits nach den erfolgten Gesprächen am XXX seine Zustimmung bezüglich Ihrer Einstellung signalisiert. Die offizielle Personalrat-Zustimmung wird am XXX erwartet. Bei der Zustimmung handelt es sich um eine Formalität.

Google translate for this passage states:

It is with great pleasure that I inform you today that your
application XXX was successful. We would like to hire you as soon as
possible. The staff council has already signaled its approval of your
employment after the discussions on XXX. Official staff council
approval is expected on XXX. Consent is a formality.


To close voters, this is a question about different legal standards regarding taking up employment. In some jurisdictions (for example the US) such an email may be all the work contract there is and therefore could be considered legally binding. In Germany this is not the case. This is universal in Germany and not specific to OPs employer.

@quarague While the title question is general, the answer to this particular question in the body text really turns on the specific language of the email in this case (making it much more individualized) and not on the method by which it is communicated.


Is an email legally binding for a governmental job confirmation in
Germany?

Not this email.
When it says: "Official staff council approval is expected on XXX" ("Die offizielle Personalrat-Zustimmung wird am XXX erwartet."), this means that you aren't actually hired yet, even though the author of the email thinks that it is nearly certain that you will be hired.
The author of the email probably doesn't have the legal authority to enter into a binding agreement to hire you at the time the email was written.
Also, to be clear, in answer to the title question, an email worded differently, saying, for example, "the Official Staff Council approved your hiring this afternoon and I have signed the attached Arbeitsvertrag. You are hired as soon as you sign it," probably wouldn't be invalid simply because it was delivered in an electronic form rather than being physically transmitted in a dead tree piece of paper. (Even if the law required a physical piece of paper, the email would probably create a legally binding obligation to commit it to paper in that scenario.)

They might have the authority but only after the staff council has exercised their right according to §78 BPersVG (or an equivalent state law). The (annoying and common) issue in OP's case seems to be that the official approval can only be granted at the next scheduled meeting.

The important sentence is "We would like to hire you as soon as possible. " They haven't done anything yet, they say they would like to, once you have a signed contract then you will be hired, not before. While in the US, such an email might be all the work contract there is, in Germany there is a paper document usually entitled 'Arbeitsvertrag'=work contract that is signed by both parties. If you have that, you are hired, everything else is at best a statement of intention.

@quarague The message is a bit stronger than “We would like to hire you”. They have started the process of hiring and they expect that process to complete without issues. No negotiations necessary, no further documents necessary. From my experience in the German public sector, OP is as good as hired, although legally they aren’t, of course.

@Roland Wrong, there is one document necessary still: the person hiring signing the contract, after the employee council agreed.

@Trish Well, obviously.
